# How to set the selected field of combo box within the view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two options in a combo box.

```
<select id="selLang">
    <option value="/en" >english</option>
    <option value="/fr" >french</option>
</select>
```

When i choose the second option the page is refreshed and the selected option isn't displayed in the top of the combo box (i mean, as the selected item.)
I want to set the selected option to be the selected option which is in the top of the combo box- within the view.
so my question is just how can i do it? or maybe i have to create a cookie? and if so -how do i do t-h-a-t?

Perhaps it's a silly question, but i'm quite new in this region.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you generating this dropdown? Are you using some helper? Are you using view models? Which controller action are you invoking when the user changes selection? How are you invoking it? How/where do you intend to persist the user choice on the server because as you know HTTP is a stateless protocol.

Comment: sorry i was wrong, i ment in the view - where i'm generating it..

Comment: this doesn't answer any of the questions in my previous comment. Yes, you can indeed use a cookie to store the value.

Comment: I used this order: var urlString = window.location.host;
                   var Lang = $("#selLang")[0].value;         window.location = "http://" + urlString + "/" + Lang;

Comment: and this is automatically refresh the page and make the page be in french at the time it's "english" in the select box.

Comment: I get that cookie thing is complicated so i prefer to use "if the url is fr than the selected value is french"...this seems very simple to me

Comment: and this : window.location.pathname is exactly the value of the option.(and it remains the same after the page refreshing.) that's how i was thinking to get over the problem and avoid using in cookie.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `selected` attribute of the option. you can do it as follows:

```
<select id="selLang">
    <option value="en" >english</option>
    <option value="fr" selected="selected" >french</option>
</select>
```

Hope this is what you wanted..

see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/anilkamath87/yP9Zq/)

Comment: but i need it to change just in case someone did change it and not from the start,

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you taking a look at the [ASP.NET MVC localization guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html) which will provide you with some nice ideas about how to implement this.

Comment: It's a realy great guide and i used it to replace the language. I highly recommend on this site! but he use links to change the language and not dropdownlist...

Answer (score 0):

First, why when you choose the second option, the page is refreshed. Do you have any JavaScript function in action to post your form.

I ask that, because HTML `<select>` tag's change won't initiate an HTTP Post request. So, please update an explanation for that.

However, let's go back to your question. You can try this:

```
<select id='selLang' name='selLang'>
    <option value="/en" >english</option>
    <option value="/fr" >french</option>
</select>
```

This will cause the `<select>` tag to become a [successful control](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) during a POST request. This means that you can use this to create a script like:

```
$(function(){
    $('#selLang').val('@HttpContext.Request["selLang"]');
});
```

Comment: actualy i have this:
var urlString = window.location.host; 
var Lang = $("#selLang")[0].value; 
window.location = "http://" + urlString + Lang;(this is automatically refresh the page)

and this: window.location.pathname - is exactly the value of the option.(and it remains the same after the page refreshing.) that's how i was thinking to get over the problem and avoid using a cookie.